# Set focus to a usercontrol when it is made visible

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, command, focus

I am showing a `MessageBox` and want the user to be able to copy the contents of the message  using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. The problem is that I can't seem to set focus to the dialog.

The `MessageBox` is implemented in MVVM. To show it I just make a usercontrol visible (centre screen) and disable the main view.

The copy command is implemented using a Prism DelegateCommand:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="C" Modifiers="Control" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

If I tab onto on of the message box button the CopyCommand fires. However I cannot get it to work initially when the dialog is shown.

How do I get the usercontrol to accept focus or to attach the KeyBinding to the whole of the usercontrol?

**`Note:`** I need an MVVM solution as don't want any code in the code behind file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations when using MVVM pattern and need to interact with the user interface, I always try to implement this solution through an *attached behavior*. Attached behavior is very powerful and convenient solution that fully satisfies the MVVM pattern, which can also be used in the Blend (with a pre-defined interface).

In this case, I created an attached behavior `VisibleFocusBehavior`, which set a `IsVisibleChanged` event handler, wherein the focus is set in the case of the visibility of the element.

To avoid the appearance of dotted box, when the control gets focus, I set `FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}` for UserControl.

**`VisibleFocusBehavior`**

```
public class VisibleFocusBehavior
{
    #region IsFocusEnabled Dependency Property

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusEnabledProperty;

    public static void SetIsFocusEnabled(DependencyObject DepObject, bool value)
    {
        DepObject.SetValue(IsFocusEnabledProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsFocusEnabled(DependencyObject DepObject)
    {
        return (bool)DepObject.GetValue(IsFocusEnabledProperty);
    }

    #endregion

    #region BringToFrontBehavior Constructor

    static VisibleFocusBehavior()
    {
        IsFocusEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocusEnabled",
                                                            typeof(bool),
                                                            typeof(VisibleFocusBehavior),
                                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, IsFocusTurn));
    }

    #endregion

    #region IsFocusTurn

    private static void IsFocusTurn(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement element = sender as UIElement;

        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
        {
            if (element != null)
            {
                element.IsVisibleChanged += new DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler(ElementIsVisibleChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ElementIsVisibleChanged Handler

    private static void ElementIsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) 
    {
        UIElement visibilityElement = sender as UIElement;

        if (visibilityElement.IsVisible == true) 
        {
            visibilityElement.Focus();
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**`Example of using`**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlFocusHelp.TestUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlFocusHelp"             
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" 
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         xmlns:AttachedBehaviors="clr-namespace:UserControlFocusHelp.AttachedBehaviors"
         AttachedBehaviors:VisibleFocusBehavior.IsFocusEnabled="True"
         FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}">

<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="C" 
                Modifiers="Control"
                Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" />
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

**`Test window`**

`XAML`

```
<Grid>
    <local:TestUserControl x:Name="TestUserControl"
                           Width="300"
                           Height="300"
                           Focusable="True"
                           Visibility="Collapsed" />

    <Button Width="100"
            Height="30" 
            Content="Visible" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Click="Button_Click" />
</Grid>
```

`Code-behind`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestUserControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

> Full example is available at this [link](https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3FC95A33B3F2DE8A!120).

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  There are so many solutions out there that only work when the control is already visible, or intermittently fail in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple way to set focus to a control. Here's an example:

```
<UserControl
         FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=txtNickname}">
<Grid>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtNickname" Grid.Row="1" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```